# Cannot get API Json data to display on Django Template

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to get data from a JSON, which was fetched from an API I created to display on my Django Template.

The API is just a simple API which store a post hit counts and its id, the json is formatted as below:

```
[
    {
        "object_pk": 3,
        "hits": 15
    },
    {
        "object_pk": 1,
        "hits": 21
    }
]
```

Here is my **views.py** file:

```
class BlogListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "home.html"


class BlogDetailView(HitCountDetailView, DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "post_detail.html"
    count_hit = True
    data = {
        "hits": get_cloudapi_data(),
    }


class ResumePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "resume.html"
```

And my **service.py** file, which have the **get_cloudapi_data()** function:

```
def get_cloudapi_data():
    url = "my-api-address"
    r = requests.get(url)
    hitcount = r.json()
    return hitcount
```

Below is my HTML template, **post_detail.html** used for displaying this data:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load hitcount_tags %}

{% block content %}
<div class="post-entry">
    <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
    <p> {% get_hit_count for post %} views</p>
    <p> {{ post.body }}</p>

    {% for hit in hits %}

    <p>{{ hit.object_pk }}</p>
    <p>{{ hit.hits }}</p>

    {% endfor %}
</div>




{% endblock content %}
```

It only shows the title, body and the hit count retrieve with the hitcount app not my API data

I have printed out the **hitcount** and the **data** if it would help

**hitcount**

```
[{'object_pk': 3, 'hits': 15}, {'object_pk': 1, 'hits': 21}]
```

**data**

```
{'hits': [{'object_pk': 3, 'hits': 15}, {'object_pk': 1, 'hits': 21}]}
```

I am new to working with an API with Django, so I am unsure where I went wrong.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't need `{% endfor %}` for the first loop? Could you do it the same way you did for the second loop and report back

Comment: What is that exactly? `{% get_hit_count for post %}`

Comment: that is the hit count retrieved by using the hit count app template tags. https://django-hitcount.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but i don't need the `{% endfor %} ` for the template, line 6,7,8 work just find, its the one in the for loop that does not show